# NullReferenceException when accessing an IEnumerable<T> of a custom class

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, boids

### Goal

I am designing a [boid](https://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/) system using Unity. I deal with the awareness radius by adding a boid to the "Swarm" list when it enters a collider. In order to find the force for each boid, I need to cycle through the swarm list, access the "Boid" class, and retrieve velocity and position.

### Problem

The Boid classes from each swarm entity are added to a new list, and passed to the physics controller. However, a NullReferenceException is thrown at line 96, and I don't understand why that variable would be null. As far as I know, accessing a populated `Enumerable<Boid>` using foreach should have variables within.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Boid.Alignment (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] boids) (at Assets/Scripts/Boid.cs:96)
>   Boid.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Boid.cs:42)

After testing, it seems it is thrown when accessing any part of the new list of Boids.

Why does my new list contain no data? Is there a better way to handle a 2D implementation of boids in a 3D space? Is there a resource I can use to better understand Linq?

P.S. I am very new to using Linq systems, and most of this code is taken from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqtqltqcQhw) and [this Unity project script](https://github.com/RafaelKuebler/Flocking/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Flocking.cs)

### Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Boid : MonoBehaviour
{
// Global Variables
public Boid_Settings settings;

// Local Variables
public Rigidbody body;
public Vector2 acceleration;
public Vector2 velocity
{
    get
    { return new Vector2(body.velocity.x, body.velocity.z); }
    set
    { body.velocity = new Vector3(value.x, body.velocity.y, value.y); }
}
public Vector2 position
{
    get
    { return new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.z); }
}
public List<GameObject> swarm = new List<GameObject>();
public List<GameObject> targets = new List<GameObject>();


// Functions
private void Start()
{
    float angle = Random.Range(0, 2 * Mathf.PI);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
    velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle));
}

private void Update()
{
    IEnumerable<Boid> boids = swarm.Select(o => o.GetComponent<Boid>()).ToList(); //Line 40

    Vector2 alignment = Alignment(boids); //LINE 42
    Vector2 separation = Separation(boids);
    Vector2 cohesion = Cohesion(boids);

    acceleration = settings.alignmentWeight * alignment + settings.cohesionWeight * cohesion + settings.seperationWeight * separation;

    UpdatePhysics();
}

// Entity Awareness Assignment
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.CompareTag("Zombie"))
    { swarm.Add(collider.gameObject); }
    else if (collider.CompareTag("Player") || collider.CompareTag("Lure"))
    { targets.Add(collider.gameObject); }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.CompareTag("Zombie"))
    { swarm.Remove(collider.gameObject); }
    else if (collider.CompareTag("Player") || collider.CompareTag("Lure"))
    {
        targets.Remove(collider.gameObject);
        StartCoroutine(LingerTarget(collider.gameObject));
    }
}

IEnumerator LingerTarget(GameObject target)
{
    targets.Add(target);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(settings.lingerTime);
    targets.Remove(target);
}


// Core Boid Logic
public void UpdatePhysics()
{
    // Apply the acceleration, and then limit the speed to the maximum.
    Vector2 UncappedVelocity = velocity + acceleration;
    velocity = ApplyLimit(UncappedVelocity, settings.maxSpeed);

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(velocity.y, velocity.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    body.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
}

private Vector2 Alignment(IEnumerable<Boid> boids)
{
    Vector2 velocity = Vector2.zero;
    if (!boids.Any()) return velocity;

    foreach (Boid boid in boids)
    { velocity += boid.velocity; } //LINE 96
    velocity /= boids.Count();

    Vector2 steer = Steer(velocity.normalized * settings.maxSpeed);
    return steer;
}

private Vector2 Cohesion(IEnumerable<Boid> boids)
{
    if (!boids.Any()) return Vector2.zero;

    Vector2 sumPositions = Vector2.zero;
    foreach (Boid boid in boids)
    { sumPositions += boid.position; }
    Vector2 average = sumPositions / boids.Count();
    Vector2 direction = average - position;

    Vector2 steer = Steer(direction.normalized * settings.maxSpeed);
    return steer;
}

private Vector2 Separation(IEnumerable<Boid> boids)
{
    Vector2 direction = Vector2.zero;
    boids = boids.Where(o => Vector3.Distance(o.transform.position, position) <= settings.avoidanceRadius);
    if (!boids.Any()) return direction;

    foreach (Boid boid in boids)
    {
        Vector2 difference = position - boid.position;
        direction += difference.normalized / difference.magnitude;
    }
    direction /= boids.Count();

    Vector2 steer = Steer(direction.normalized * settings.maxSpeed);
    return steer;
}

private Vector2 Steer(Vector2 desired)
{
    Vector2 steer = desired - velocity;
    steer = ApplyLimit(steer, settings.maxSteerForce);

    return steer;
}

// Calculation Helpers
private Vector2 ApplyLimit(Vector2 baseVector, float limit)
{
    if (baseVector.sqrMagnitude > limit * limit)
    { baseVector = baseVector.normalized * limit; }
    return baseVector;
}
}
```

The Boid_Settings Module:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Boid_Settings : ScriptableObject
{
// Boid
public float maxSpeed = 5;
public float avoidanceRadius = 1;
public float maxSteerForce = 3;

public float lingerTime = 2.5f;
public float alignmentWeight = 1;
public float cohesionWeight = 1;
public float seperationWeight = 1;
public float targetWeight = 1;

// Spawner
public float awarenessRadius = 2.5f;
}
```

### Context Pictures

Proof the boid classes have data to be read
[image: Proof the boid classes have data to be read]
Unity Enviroment & Boid.cs Attachment
[image: Unity Enviroment & Boid.cs Attachment]
Unity Boid Boid.body Component
[image: Unity Boid Boid.body Component]
Each Boid finds two swarm mates when the game is run
[image: Boid Population Proof]

Comment: check Boid.cs line number 96.

Comment: That is where the error occurs, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Sove67 It looks like from the exception stack trace the error appeasrs in the `Update()` method when you pass variable `boids` to `Alignment(boids);`. Set a break point on this line and check if `boids` is `null` from the previous line of `IEnumerable<Boid> boids = swarm.Select(o => o.GetComponent<Boid>()).ToList();
`

Comment: @RyanWilson I added *if (boids == null) { Debug.Log("No Data Attached"); }* before the Alignment(boids) but it was not called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Also did you check `body` is not null?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I know what a NullReferenceException is, but don't know why accessing part of this IEnumerable<T> returns null rather than a Vector2 as I would expect.

Comment: Please could you add some comments to your code to highlight lines 96 and 42 in the appropriate files.

Comment: Further, I don't understand how `Result of printing self's velocity` has anything to do with the `Alignment()` method. It feels like you're conflating multiple issues here, please consider editing the question to remove the irrelevant bits.

Comment: @IanKemp Lines have been commented, Thanks. The velocity is a check to ensure the boids do have data to be read, and the problem is in the IEnumerable<T> not the class itself. Is that obvious enough for me to remove the picture?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I was assigning null data, because the GetComponent function at line 40 found the "Body" of the boids, which did not have a Boid script attached. When searching with GetComponentInChildren, the array is populated and values are given.

The Old Line:

`IEnumerable<Boid> boids = swarm.Select(o => o.GetComponent<Boid>()).ToList();`

The New Line:

`IEnumerable<Boid> boids = swarm.Select(o => o.GetComponentInChildren<Boid>()).ToList();`